# Is Ipad 2 enough for Iphone/Ipad apps debugging?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to start programming for iOS-devices. I have mac mini and IPad 2. My question is: "Is IPad 2 enough  for developing and debugging apps for IPhone and IPad"? Or I need to bye IPhone for debug IPhone apps? Of course I mean only apps without special IPhone features (like call, sms,  etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say it depends.

If you're going to develop easy standard UI based app for iPad only, then iPad 2 is enough. If you're going to develop games or apps which need a lot of resources (e.g. drawing app) then I'd advise you to have both - iPad and iPad 2. E.g. I test my iPad only app on both iPad and iPad 2 as their performance is totally different. Also I left iOS 4 on iPad just in case, to have one device with iOS < 5.0

Regarding developing for iPhone using iPad... I wouldn't recommend that. As people mentioned hardware is different, some API (e.g. for sending SMS) is missing on iPad.

So, if you're serious about your app - spend few hundred bucks for several devices.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Software needs to be thoroughly tested on its platform before it is released regardless of the hardware and OS used.  Therefore if you are developing for Windows you need to test it on computers that have all the versions you wish to support.  Same goes for Macintosh, Android, LINUX, and iOS.  Otherwise you run a big risk.

That being said iPad and iPhones do not have exactly the same operating systems although they are very close in many respects.  The iOS simulator is very impressive but it can mislead the developer because it has far more memory and computing power depending on the development machine since it is running on a desktop of laptop.

Therefore I would recommend that you have both if you wish to release software for both.

Comment: In addition to that: iPad, iPad 2 and iPhone x.y may have all the same iOS version, but all of them have different facilities. When it works ok in the simulator, it may reveal surprises on the device. So the application should say, what device and what iOS-versions it supports, and it should be tested in deep before releasing it.

Answer (score 2):

You should at least invest in an iPhone 3G[S], or an iPod Touch 3rd gen. The hardware is not the same than an iPad2, and if your program is computing-intensive, you'll notice a real difference.